# Converting a long nested Excel formula to c#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, excel-formula

I am tasked to transform an **Excel VBA to a web-based application**. I am using **Web Forms**. I am stuck with a long Excel formula but I have converted half of the long formula into `C#`.

Here is the Excel formula:

```
IF(AND(D7="u", H7/F7>1), 0, INDEX(Scoring!$O$8:$O$10, SUMPRODUCT(--(E28 <= Scoring!$N8:$N10),--(E28 >= Scoring!$N8:$N10), ROW(INDIRECT("'Scoring'!$M1:$M3"))))
```

While here is my progress on the **C# method**. I need help on the **ELSE** part:

```
IF (variable = "u" && ((CurrentValue / AcceptedValue) > 1)){
    return 0;
ELSE {
    // the INDEX clause on the Excel Formula
}
```

**O8 - O10** values are `{2, 1, 0}`

**N8 - N10** values are `{1, 1.5, 9999999999}`

**E28** is `0`

I have also got the result of the remainder of the formula piece by piece. I just need **guidance on how to put it in C#**.

```
=INDEX(Scoring!$O$8:$O$10, SUMPRODUCT({1,1,1}, {0,0,0}, 1))
```

The `double minus(--)` made it return **0/1** instead of **true/false.** `ROW(INDIRECT($M1-$M3))` is equivalent to `1`.

I could use some help on transforming the Excel formula into C# code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between using True,False, 1,0 as the last value of a VLOOKUP in excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219141/what-is-the-difference-between-using-true-false-1-0-as-the-last-value-of-a-vloo)

Comment: How/What collections are you using for the data, or is it still residing in Excel?

Comment: Look at what sumproduct does, it looks like its using logical statements to sift through 3 `Sum((0,0,1) *(a,b,c))=(1*c)`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the Current value is stored in a dictionary since it is retrieved using a key. The **accepted value** is a fixed value (ex. 100). I need help on generating the ELSE clause.

Comment: Based on your description of the inputs, the SUMPRODUCT would be using `SUMPRODUCT({1,1,1},{0,0,0},1)` which gives me an error. It is expecting an array for the 3rd argument. Or, how do you get that `--(E28 <= Scoring!$N8:$N10)` evaluates to 1 and not {1,1,1} ?

Comment: You're right about the `SUMPRODUCT({1,1,1},{0,0,0},1)`. The 3rd argument is this **ROW(INDIRECT($M1:$M3))** which returns `1`. M1:M3 = {"", "Range Start", 0} @RobinMackenzie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some C# code to replicate this part of your formula:

`INDEX(Scoring!$O$8:$O$10, SUMPRODUCT(--(E28 <= Scoring!$N8:$N10),--(E28 >= Scoring!$N8:$N10), ROW(INDIRECT("'Scoring'!$M1:$M3")))`

In the code I've had to assign the array `{1, 1, 1}` for `ROW(INDIRECT("'Scoring'!$M1:$M3"))`. There is some ambiguity in your question around the action of `SUMPRODUCT`. According to [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

> Multiplies corresponding components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products.

But some of your detail in the question makes me think you are thinking that each array get summed up and then those results get multiplied together. Anyway, check out the comments in the code below to follow the logic:

```
// inputs
double[] o8o10 = new double[] { 2, 1, 0 }; // Scoring!$O$8:$O$10
double[] n8n10 = new double[] { 1, 1.5, 9999999999 }; // Scoring!$N8:$N10
double e28 = 0; // E28

// entries to SUMPRODUCT
List<int> test1 = new List<int>();
List<int> test2 = new List<int>();
Array.ForEach(n8n10, x => { test1.Add((e28 <= x) ? 0 : 1); });
Array.ForEach(n8n10, x => { test2.Add((e28 >= x) ? 0 : 1); });
// ROW(INDIRECT("'Scoring'!$M1:$M3")) should be an array !
List<int> test3 = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1 }; 

// evalue SUMPRODUCT
int sumProductResult = 0;
for (var i=0; i<test1.Count; i++)
{
    sumProductResult += test1[i] * test2[i] * test3[i];
}

// evalute INDEX
double indexResult = 0;
indexResult = o8o10[sumProductResult];

// output
Console.WriteLine(indexResult);
Console.ReadKey();
```

The output for me is `2` because that is the 0th element of the `o8o10` array. We get `0` for the array index because

`=SUMPRODUCT({1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1})`

resolves to:

`=SUM(1*0*1, 1*0*1, 1*0*1}`

Which gives `0`.

HTH

Comment: Could you enlighten me a little bit on the `Array.ForEach` syntax?

Comment: It's a quick way of saying `for(var i=0; i<n8n10for(var i=0; i<n8n10.Length; i++) { if(n8n10[i] >= 0) { test1.Add(0); } else { test1.Add(1); }}`. `x` is the current element of the array `n8n10` as it is being iterated over by `ForEach` and then the test is applied via ternary operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`ROW(INDIRECT("'Scoring'!$M1:$M3"))` actually evaluates to `{1; 2; 3}` and

`--(E28 <= Scoring!$N8:$N10),--(E28 >= Scoring!$N8:$N10)` is `--(E28 = Scoring!$N8:$N10)`

so the `SUMPRODUCT` formula is just:

```
(E28 = Scoring!$N8) * 1 + (E28 = Scoring!$N9) * 2 + (E28 = Scoring!$N10) * 3
```

and in C#:

```
double[] n8n10 = { 1, 2, 3 }; double e28 = 2; 

double sumProduct = n8n10.Select((d, i) d == e28 ? i + 1 : 0).Sum();
```

---

**But**! because `Scoring!$O$8:$O$10` is only 3 cells and the SUMPRODUCT can in theory result in more than 3, the actual aim of the INDEX SUMPRODUCT part seems to be something like this:

```
double[] o8o10 = { 4, 5, 6 }, n8n10 = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
double e28 = 2, result = o8o10[0];                     // INDEX(array, 0) results in array

if      (n8n10[1] == e28) result = o8o10[1];
else if (n8n10[2] == e28) result = o8o10[2];
```